# Unknown text format saved in database from cyrillic

Tags: php, joomla

After saving bulgarian word `Черно` e.g. cyrillic symbols, in database it is saved as `u0427u0435u0440u0435u043d`. I am working on `joomla` if that matters somehow. How can I convert it it back to cyrillic format ? I don't what more should I give as example or something. Don't know what action `joomla` performes before saving to database.

Comment: What's the database charset?

Comment: As I see it is `utf8`. EDIT. I see the column collation is `uft8mb4_unicode_ci`

Comment: You need to check your application why it's saving this way. If you run `echo json_decode('"\u0427\u0435\u0440\u0435\u043d"');` you will see the word `Черен`. The backslashes seems to be escaped or removed before saving in database.

Comment: I see. Thank you!

Comment: When you have a question that might benefit from the support of volunteers who have an intimate understanding of Joomla and its extensions, please post your question on [joomla.se] Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 0):

While saving data to the table, proper encoding gets applied. Usually, you don't need to care about that, this happens transparently.

The only place where I stumbled upon is the length of your data field. You need to specify it long enough to cover the encoding, too.